# Canvas Uploaded Image exclude non editable Layer using svg

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

I am using [Svg Image](https://scalethread.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/preview.svg) for product customization. On page load I am loading a product for customization.
Product Image has two layer. Phone case [editable] and camera above that is non editable.
I am able to drag and resize image in canvas using below code. But uploaded image is showing above camera when it comes under camera section. camera layer should be above uploaded image always.

**Initaliza Variable**

```
            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCan');
            var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var bkg = new Image();
            var tempimage;
            bkg.onload = function() {
                canvas.width = bkg.width;
                canvas.height = bkg.height;
            }
            bkg.src = 'product-without-customization.svg';
            
            var mouse = {
                x: 0
                , y: 0
            };
            var obj = {
                x: 0
                , y: 0
                , w: 100
                , h: 100
            };
            var u = [];
```

**Events**

```
$('#fileLoader').on('change', addImage);
```

**Functions**

```
            function draw() {
                cxt.save();
                cxt.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                cxt.drawImage(bkg, 0, 0);
                for (i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
                    u[i].update(i);
                }
                cxt.restore();
            }

            function addImage(e) {
                var t = new FileReader;
                t.onload = function (event) {
                    tempimage = new addNew(event.target.result);
                    u.push(tempimage);
                }
                t.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
            }

            function addNew(e) {
                var objnew = this
                    , drag = false
                    , rsize = false
                    , vsize = false;
                var vs = {
                    h: 0
                    , y: 0
                };
                var offimage = {
                    x: 0
                    , y: 0
                    , a: false
                }
                this.x = 50;
                this.y = 50;
                this.w = 100;
                this.h = 100;
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = e;
                this.update = function (arg) {
                    if (mousedown) {
                        if (!offimage.a) {
                            offimage.x = mouse.x - objnew.x;
                            offimage.y = mouse.y - objnew.y;
                            offimage.a = true;
                        }
                        var l = objnew.x
                            , r = objnew.x + objnew.w
                            , t = objnew.y
                            , b = objnew.y + objnew.h;
                        if (mouse.x < r && mouse.x > (r - 10) && mouse.y < b && mouse.y > t) {
                            if (!gotit) {
                                gotit = true;
                                rsize = true;
                                ontop = arg;
                            }
                        }
                        if (mouse.x < r && mouse.x > l && mouse.y < t && mouse.y > (t - 10)) {
                            if (!gotit) {
                                gotit = true;
                                vsize = true;
                                vs.h = objnew.h;
                                vs.y = mouse.y;
                                ontop = arg;
                            }
                        }
                        if (mouse.x < (r - 10) && mouse.x > l && mouse.y < b && mouse.y > t) {
                            if (!gotit) {
                                gotit = true;
                                drag = true;
                                ontop = arg;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        drag = false;
                        rsize = false;
                        vsize = false;
                        canvas.style.cursor = "default";
                        offimage.a = false;
                    }
                    if (drag) {
                        objnew.x = mouse.x - offimage.x;
                        objnew.y = mouse.y - offimage.y;
                        canvas.style.cursor = "move";
                        cxt.lineWidth = 1;
                        cxt.strokeRect(objnew.x, objnew.y, objnew.w, objnew.h);
                    }
                    if (rsize) {
                        canvas.style.cursor = "col-resize";
                        objnew.w = mouse.x - objnew.x;
                    }
                    if (vsize) {
                        canvas.style.cursor = "row-resize";
                        //console.log(objnew.h + ' C=' + mouse.y + ' O=' + vs.h + ' B=' +vs.y);
                        objnew.h = vs.h + (vs.y - mouse.y);
                        objnew.y = mouse.y;
                    }
                    cxt.drawImage(img, objnew.x, objnew.y, objnew.w, objnew.h);
                }
            }
```

Here is [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ShaanSetia/45s7L3xz/7/) for code implementation.

How can I get uploaded image below camera?

**Getting Result** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCFUz.png)

**Expected Result** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD7S9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the `globalCompositeOperation` prop which helps us dictate the order of the shapes we draw on the canvas.

Setting `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"` should do the trick.

```
function draw() {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // This is what you want
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  ctx.drawImage(bkg, 0, 0);

  for (i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
    u[i].update(i);
  }

  ctx.restore();
}
```

There are other values you can play around with which you can find in the docs for globalCompositeOperation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing#globalcompositeoperation)

Here's an updated version of your [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfL8ncqg/).

***Note that I changed the variable name from `cxt` to `ctx` in the fiddle. If you copy/paste the code you'll have to change it back if you are using `cxt` anywhere else.***

This is what it looks like with the `globalCompositeOperation` value set.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Image is going outside the editable area. Can we restrict it?

Comment: This is happening because of the way the svg is generated. There is a `path` in the svg that creates a white border around the image. The space between the border and the image is what makes it look like the background image is overflowing the svg. In actuality, it is confined in the svg properly. 

Your best bet would be to modify the svg to remove that path, and load the modified svg locally or if you have access to scalethread, upload and reference the new svg from there.

Comment: Removing path does not work. Border image is in rectangle shape that's why it's showing outside the border image.